# Does HPA also scale pods when the pods are configured to run on AKS Virtual Nodes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

Simple question that I seem to get different or non-committal answers to:
If our pods are configured to run on Virtual nodes, and we add the/a HPA(horizontal Pod Autoscaler) for each pod, will they also scale on virtual nodes, similar to how they scale on regular nodes/node pools?

I've asked support, and they keep sending me the same links that don't answer my question.

Additional info: we have pods that scale using HPA on a nodepool with regular nodes(1 to 5 replicas). I can also configure our pods to work on Virtual Nodes with requests set. I'm just not a 100% sure whether the pods are being scaled, because I don't see any scaling events.

Answer (score 0):

Using HPA Virtual Nodes auto scale won't work because, AKS cluster that presents ACI as a virtual node not a Pods.  if requirement is high burst demands, then scale with virtual nodes and Azure Container Instances.

HPA will increase / decrease the number of replicas automatically to maintain an average CPU utilization across all pods of recommended percentage.

I have found one solution over [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-node-autoscale) which will help to auto scale Virtual Nodes.

**Replication Process:**

I have successfully reproduced the solution and it's working fine with HPA implementation after making some changes on enablement of **virtual nodes addons**.

Step1: Created a Vnet with address prefix with 10.0.0.0/8 and subnets myAKSSubnet : 10.240.0.0/16 and myVirtualNodeSubnet 10.241.0.0/16

Step2: Created a cluster with default node count as 1 and mapped to subnet id  myVirtualNodeSubnet
[image]

Step3: Enabled virtual nodes addons by using below command

```
az aks enable-addons --resource-group <resourcegroupName>--name <CluserName> --addons virtual-node --subnet-name <Subnetname>
```

step4:
Connect cluser  and check the node details:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group <ResourcegroupName>--name <CluserName>
kubectl get nodes
```

step5: deploy same application without HPA

```
kubectl apply -f <app>.yaml
```

[image]

step6:
Apply HPA with the same application
[image]

step7:
upon verification of pods it will autoscale to 2 now
[image]

Note: Upon enable on virtual nodes addons HPA is working.

Comment: Thanks for the information. 

I already have that link, my question was more related to whether HPA can scale pods on virtual nodes(ACI) automatically, without having to resort to going the Prometheus route. 

So in short - use HPA to scale pods on virtual node(s) instead of regular nodes, starting with say one replica, and setting HPA to scale between 1 and 6 replicas, using only the virtual node(s).

Comment: Replicated as requested. Updated replica set as 2 for virtual node on HPA and is working. Thank for the information, updated the solution with "Replication Process".